# How to declare specific address as a variable

Tags: assembly, marie

In Marie assembly, how can I declare a specific address as a variable?

x should have a value of hex `2c` and value should be at address `0015`
Currently, I have code:

```
load x
add x      \ 2x
store x
halt
x, hex 2c
```

I could load `2c` to the accumulator, and store it at address `0015`, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently proper command is `org hhh` where `hhh` are hex digits, and there must be 3 of them — so, for 15<sub>16</sub> need to use `org 015`, or for 15<sub>10</sub> then `org 00F`.

I have tested this on [marie.js](https://marie.js.org/?unicode); it gives the error `unknown operator org` if 3 digits are not supplied.

Sadly, fyi, I'm having trouble using `org` in any position except first, i.e. in front of all the code & data.  So, if you want to put the code ahead of the data, that's going to be difficult without counting lines of code.  The following `org` usage will place `x` at 0x015.

```
org 011
load x
add x      
store x
halt
x, hex 2c
```

---

Alternately, you might do the following:

```
org 014
jump start
x,  hex 2c
start, load x
...
...
```

Though this will place the code after the data, it involves only counting one line of code, i.e. the `jump start`.

---

Note: marie.js will load the initial PC with the org location, so you can relocate code & data to anywhere and it will still start the simulation at the beginning of that code & data.